# ruby on rails has_one association with unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, belongs-to, has-one

Hey I have a model foo that `has_one :bar`. And bar `belongs_to :foo`. I was wondering if there is a way to augment the has_one such that no two bars can belong to the same foo. I looked at the documentation for has_one and it seems like there is no :uniq parameter which I am allowed to specify. So do I have to create a custom validation to achieve this? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You do not need a custom validation, just enforce uniqueness of bar for any given foo

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates_uniqueness_of :foo_id
end
```

Comment: This would ensure that no two foos have the same bar, but @dhruvg is looking to ensure that no two bars belong to the *same* foo.

Comment: As mentioned by @pynix-wang, validation of uniqueness does not guaranty anything in concurrent environments. You should use unique index

Answer (score 3):

add a uniq index to foo_id in table bars so you can not create 2 bars with same foo_id, so only one bar can belongs to foo

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of` may not uniq in a concurrency environment.

Comment: you might also need to create a unique index and/or a foreign key constraint on the supplier column for the accounts table.[From Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your own validation, because two different record of Foo has no idea about others related record (Bar)

Comment: Irrelevent.  That would be of concern if he wanted no two Foo's to have the same Bar.  But that's not what he asked.